# Destructure a list two elements at a time (Clojure)

Tags: haskell, clojure, pattern-matching, destructuring

This problem takes many forms.  For example, given the input '(1 2 3 4 5 6), we might want to swap the values between even and odd pairs.  The output would be '(2 1 4 3 6 5).

In Haskell, this is rather easy:

```
helper [] = []
helper [x] = [x]
helper (x : y : ys) = y : x : helper ys
```

I wrote some Clojure code to accomplish the same task, but I feel that there is probably a cleaner way.  Any suggestions on how to improve this?

```
(defn helper [[x y & ys]]
  (cond
   (nil? x) (list)
   (nil? y) (list x)
   :else (lazy-seq (cons y (cons x (helper ys))))))
```

Ideally the list would be consumed and produced lazily.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(for [[a b] (partition 2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
      i [b a]]
  i)
```

OR something resembling the haskell version:

```
(defn helper
  ([] (list))
  ([x] (list x))
  ([x y & r] (concat [y x] (apply helper r))))

(apply helper '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

Comment: Your second method is conceptually what I was after.  I tried using only a single argument and then destructuring the list, but this fails since each overload has the same arity.  Your way is more lispy too!

Comment: I especially like the first version. You'll want to use `partition-all` though.

Comment: In the second version, you could also use `list*`, which is similar to the Haskell colon prepend operator: `(list* y x (apply helper r))`

Answer (score 3):

This is one lazy way to do it:

```
user=> (mapcat reverse (partition 2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
(2 1 4 3 6 5)
```

Comment: You'll need to switch to `partition-all` to avoid dropping the final element if the input's length is odd. Also, `mapcat` is much preferable to `flatten`.

Comment: Good call on `mapcat`. The choice `partition` and `partition-all` depends on how OP is interpreting the list in question, so I'll leave it as before.

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding intermediate object creation (vectors / seqs to be concatenated) and in direct correspondence to the Haskell original while handling `nil` items in the input (which the approach from the question text doesn't):

```
(defn helper [[x & [y & zs :as ys] :as xs]]
  (if xs
    (lazy-seq
      (if ys
        (cons y (cons x (helper zs)))
      (list x)))))
```

Normally I'd use something like tom's answer though, only with `mapcat` rather than `flatten`:

```
(defn helper [xs]
  (mapcat reverse (partition-all 2 xs)))
```

You need to use `partition-all` rather than `partition` to avoid dropping the final element from lists of odd length.

Comment: It's good to know about _partition-all_ since I don't think Haskell has such a function on lists.  Your second method is probably what I would aim for too, unless speed was a concern.

Comment: Ahh... but Data.List.Split doesn't come with the default GHC7.  Looks like it's part of the split package from hackage? (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split)

Comment: Right. It's part of the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/) though.